# Resize the canvas output image to a specific size (width/height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a big canvas (`5000x5000`) and I want to take a picture of it and create a thumbnail on client side. I can capture the image using `canvas.toDataURL` but how do i re-size it? Do i have to create an new `$("<canvas></canvas>")` element and then put that image inside and run the `canvas2.toDataURL();` Can anyone help me with this? I can't get my head around it how to do it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tumbnail64 = null;
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
image.onload = function() {

    $c2 = $("<canvas></canvas>");
    $c2[0].width=100;
    $c2[0].height=100;
    $c2[0].getContext("2d");
    $c2[0].drawImage(image, 0, 0,100,100);
    tumbnail64 = $c2[0].toDataURL();
};
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this should work, given you don't have security restrictions on the original canvas element:

```
var resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var resizedContext = resizedCanvas.getContext("2d");

resizedCanvas.height = "100";
resizedCanvas.width = "200";

var canvas = document.getElementById("original-canvas");

resizedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 200, 100);
var myResizedData = resizedCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Where `var context` is used ?

Comment: @Alcalyn Nowhere. The OP had it in the original code, so the assumption is that it's used somewhere down the line. But it's not needed for the resizing.